# Merge [church-music] and [hymnody] tags into new [sacred-music] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [Notes not adding up to time signature, with weird white oval note](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/125043/70803) turned out to be related to a piece of Punjabi Christian sacred music.

In looking to add an appropriate tag to the question, I first thought to look for "sacred", which, to my surprise, didn't exist. On the other hand, [church-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-music) does, as does [hymnody](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hymnody), both of which I found only after doing a search for "sacred" and seeing the tags applied to questions in the search results.

I chose [hymnody](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hymnody), since it's closest, but not all sacred music is hymns, and it certainly isn't all "church music".

I suggest replacing both tags with the more musically and pluralistically inclusive [sacred](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacred) or [sacred-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacred-music).

There is highly relevant discussion in ["church-music" tag -- Do we need it, and if so, what does it cover?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2627/70803)

Comment: From a music theory point of view, is it useful to have a tag called (sacred-music), even though very different analyses would be needed for sacred music coming from different cultural and/or religious backgrounds?

Comment: @Namaskaram My feeling is that, yes, it's useful as a broad category. As questions relating to a specific culture/religion accumulate, then more specific tags will surely emerge. We certainly have many such broad tags already, like "theory" and "piano", each of which contains questions requiring vastly different analyses.

Comment: That's a good point about the (theory) and (piano) tags. Perhaps you can also suggest in your post an outline for what to put in the tag excerpt for the proposed (sacred-music) tag?

Comment: @Namaskaram I'll give that some thought. I'm certainly open to suggestions as well.

Comment: I grew up religious and interested in music, but I've never heard the term "sacred music" used in the church.  It sounds too strong.  Maybe "liturgical music", or "religious music" would be better.

Comment: I guess one question I'm not clear on is: Is it better to have broader tags—ensuring that we find relevant questions when we go looking for them—or to have narrower tags, making it easier to eliminate things irrelevant to our search? I would probably choose to keep "hymnody" and regard it as a "sub-tag" of a broader tag about music-for-religious-use, regardless of the terminology of that one. (@Edward Sure, "sacred music" is a common phrase, but I notice Wikipedia seemingly redirects both it and "religious music" to "church music"....

Comment: Personally, I'd vote "religious music," since there's plenty of music for religious use outside a church (monastic, personal devotional uses, etc.) (not to mention "church" vs mosque vs temple vs...). But "hymnody" is a very specific genre, with specific music-theory concerns, and probably deserves its own tag.

Comment: Since we don't get a plethora of music questions which would fit into any of the above, I think 'religious music' would be best - easily googled, and not contain too many questions.

Answer (score 1):

There has been enough support for the idea of new religion-related tag, that, based on the feedback, the following seems in order:

1. Create [religious-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religious-music) tag
2. Begin adding it to relevant questions
3. Propose [church-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-music) as synonym
4. Make no change regarding [hymnody](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hymnody)
5. Enlist help from the [Saptak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132745/saptak) chat room to make sure [indian-classical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-classical) questions that are, or are not, [religious-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religious-music) questions are appropriately tagged.